# How can I add two resulting columns of my query containing null values in sql

Tags: null, sum

The following is my query

```
select SupplierName, COUNT(SupplierName) as repetations, sum(capex) as sumcapex, sum(withoutcapex) as sumwithoutcapex, sum(capex + withoutcapex) as total 
from alldata
group by  SupplierName
order by repetations desc
```

capex and without capex has null values which results sum(capex + without capex) to be null.

Comment: Please tag with the RDMS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution using isnull function

---

select SupplierName, COUNT(SupplierName) as repetations, sum(capex) as sumcapex, sum(withoutcapex) as sumwithoutcapex, sum(isnull(capex, '') + isnull(withoutcapex, '')) as total

from alldata

group by  SupplierName
order by repetations desc